# Why private function can't access member variable within Javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I'm having issues understanding scoping/access of fields defined with a JavaScript object.

**Consider the following sample JavaScript object definition:**

```
function SampleObject(controlName) {

    var _controlName = controlName;

    this.Display1 = function() {
        console.log(_controlName);
    }

    this.Display2 = function() {
        Display3();
    }

    Display3 = function () {
        console.log(_controlName);
    }
}
```

**Now consider running the above object with the following example:**

```
var a = new SampleObject("Bob");
var b = new SampleObject("Fred");

a.Display1();  //==> Displays "Bob"
b.Display1();  //==> Displays "Fred"

a.Display2();  //==> Displays "Fred"
b.Display2();  //==> Displays "Fred"
```

What I'm having difficulty understanding is how to access object fields (properties) from within private functions defined within my object.
Within my example, I am confused as to why **_controlName** has the value "**Fred**" when it is displayed via **Display2()** for both objects **a** and **b**.

I suspect that is either an issue with how _**controlName** and/or **Display3()** is defined or I am unclear how scoping would work in this instance. Can someone please share some light on this?

Thanks,JohnB

Comment: Did you forget `this` in front of `Display3`? By omitting this, `Display3` is global.

Comment: Ray Toal: Good point. But when I add "this." to Display3() definition, I get javascript errors saying that Display3() is undefined. Thoughts?

Comment: You have to add `this` in both places; the declaration and the call.

Comment: RCasburn: Thanks for pointing that out. But doesn't that then expose Display3() as a public method on that object? Is there no way to define it as a "private" method? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the explanation.

In the first call, `new SampleObject("Bob");` the global variable `Display3` gets set to a function that console-logs the value `Bob`.

In the second call, `new SampleObject("Fred");` the global variable `Display3` gets set to a function that console-logs the value `Fred`.

Now your `Display1` is actually a method. Every object you create gets its own `Display1` property. So Bob's `Display1` logs `Bob` and Fred's logs `Fred`.

But because the `Display2` methods each call the global `Display3` method, they will *all* log what the function in the last assignment fo `Display3` says to log, and that will always be `Fred`.

Comment: Thanks to you, Randy and ThisIsNoZaku  for helping make this clear for me. I guess I was coming at it from a C#/VB.Net/Java mindset.

Answer (score 2):

In some other languages such as Java (where I hail from), when you are inside a method on an object, the `this` is implicit. In Javascript, this is NOT the case.

When you are assigning to `this.Display1` and `this.Display2`, you are creating properties with those names on the object pointed at by `this`. Because of `new`, this is a different object each time.

However, what's happening when you assign to `Display3` is that you are assigning to a global variable. If it doesn't exist, it is created for you. When you call `new SampleObject("Fred");` the function which originally logged "Bob" is now gone, replaced by one which prints "Fred".

If you add 'use strict'; to the top of your `SampleObject` function, which suppresses this "implicit global" behavior, you get a reference error when you try to assign to the never-declared variable `Display3`.